# How to write an Equality function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to be able to create a function to see if two types are equal. I have a type class called finite defined as follows,

`class (Bounded a, Enum a) => Finite a`

and want to be able to write a equality comparison function

`equals :: (Finite a, Eq b) => (a -> b) -> (a -> b) -> Bool`

for functions who's domain is of type Finite. For example, for a negation function:

```
neg :: Int8 -> Int8
neg n = -n
```

the return in the Main would be:

```
*Main> equals neg (\x -> x)
False
```

Comment: You create a list of the "domain", and check if both functions give the same answer for all these items.

Comment: this sounds like a property check/test, no?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: @MichaelLitchard That is not a valid reason to close a question!

Answer (score 3):

Basically what you need is to enumerate over all possible values for `a`, and check if the two functions produce the same result.

You can generate a list of all the items with `[minBound ..]`, and you can use [**`all :: Foldable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:all) to check if for all items a certain predicate is satisfied.

You thus can implement such function with:

```
equals :: (Finite a, Eq b) => (a -> b) -> (a -> b) -> Bool
equals = all (…) [minBound ..]
```

where I leave implementing the `…` part as an exercise. It should call `f` and `g` with the element of the list, and return `True` if and only if the two functions produce the same result.

Comment: @GregOSullivanne: it's not `[minBound]`, there are two dots, that is not an exercise, but simply a way to create a range list, so `[minBound ..] :: Char` will construct a list of all possible `Char`acters.

Comment: @GregOSullivanne: you can use a lambda-expression `\x -> ...` where `x` is an item from the list, and you need to map it to a bool that is true if both functions `f` and `g` produce the same result

Comment: @GregOSullivanne: no, and `map` is not a keyword: `map` is simply a function exported from the `Prelude`. The `all` will call the lambda-expression for all elements (or until it finds one item for which the lambda-expression returns `False`).